# Backup entire registry and compare with current registry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, registry

I am currently trying to code a program in C# (.NET) that is capable of backing up the entire Windows registry (including hives like HKEY_CURRENTUSER), and comparing its difference with the current Windows registry for new/changed/deleted keys. It should be capable of pointing out the exact key that changed, similar to FileSystemWatcher. It would be best if it could provide some sort of live-feed like FileSystemWatcher too. But I am open to other ideas too as long as I can get their difference.

I have tried looking into the WMI to monitor registry key changes, but it doesn't work for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and HKEY_CURRENT_USER, which is what I require monitoring too.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest attempt to solve the problem is exporting the registry to a text file before and after and doing a text comparison of those files.

The biggest problem with (lexically) comparing files created with `reg export` is that you're not always guaranteed that the keys will appear the same order (depending on which keys exist at the time of export), and worse, any key can be represented as REG_BINARY, even if it's a string. IIRC, I've seen examples of exports where a key was "expressed" as REG_BINARY one time and REG_SZ another. This will totally foil a lexical comparison.

IMHO, You're best bet is to create your own export method (not terribly difficult using recursion) that either saves the registry data in an ordered textual format or does the comparison in memory.